# Nested hashmap as result in mybatis

Tags: mybatis, nested-sets

I have a requirement im Mybatis 3, to convert the result of a select query in which contains joins to nested hashmap result.

For example, consider the following mybatis mapper entry:

```
 <select
        id="testCaseSelect"
        fetchSize="1000"
        flushCache="false"
        resultMap="testCaseResultMap" resultType="list">
SELECT TESTCASE_ID,
        TC.TITLE,
        TC.DESCRIPTION ,
        TC.CREATION_DATE ,
        TCS.STATUS_NAME,
        TCP.PRIORITY_NAME ,
        TCCBY.FIRST_NAME,
        TCCBY.LAST_NAME,
        TCST.SEQUENCE_NO ,
        TCST.DESCRIPTION ,
        TCST.EXPECTED_RESULT ,
        TCCMNTS.COMMENT_TEXT ,
        TCCMNTS.LOGGING_DATE
      FROM TESTCASE TC
      INNER JOIN TESTCASE_STATUS TCS
      ON TC.STATUS_ID=TCS.STATUS_ID
      INNER JOIN TESTCASE_PRIORITY TCP
      ON TC.PRIORITY_ID=TCP.PRIORITY_ID
      INNER JOIN USERS TCCBY
      ON TC.CREATED_BY=TCCBY.USER_ID
      LEFT JOIN TESTCASE_STEPS TCST
      ON TC.TESTCASE_ID=TCST.TESTCASE_ID
      LEFT JOIN TESTCASE_COMMENTS TCCMNTS
      ON TC.TESTCASE_ID=TCCMNTS.TESTCASE_ID WHERE TESTCASE_ID BETWEEN 326780 AND 326800
</select>
<resultMap
        id="testCaseResultMap"
        autoMapping="true"
        type="hashMap" >
        <result
            column="TESTCASE_ID"
            property="tcId" />
        <result
            column="TITLE"
            property="title" />
        <result
            column="DESCRIPTION"
            property="description" />
        <result
            column="CREATION_DATE"
            property="createdOn" />
        <association
            columnPrefix="TCS"
            javaType="hashMap"
            property="testCaseStatus" >
            <id
                column="STATUS_ID"
                property="id" />
            <result
                column="STATUS_NAME"
                property="status" />
        </association>
        <association
            columnPrefix="TCP"
            javaType="hashMap"
            property="testCasePriority" >
            <id
                column="PRIORITY_ID"
                property="id" />
            <result
                column="PRIORITY_NAME"
                property="priority" />
        </association>
        <association
            columnPrefix="TCCBY"
            javaType="hashMap"
            property="testCaseCreator" >
            <id
                column="USER_ID"
                property="id" />
            <result
                column="FIRST_NAME"
                property="firstName" />
            <result
                column="LAST_NAME"
                property="lastName" />
        </association>
        <collection
            columnPrefix="TCST"
            javaType="hashMap"
            ofType="list"
            property="testCaseSteps" >
            <id
                column="STEP_ID"
                property="id" />
            <result
                column="SEQUENCE_NO"
                property="stepNo" />
            <result
                column="description"
                property="step" />
            <result
                column="expected_result"
                property="result" />
        </collection>
        <collection
            columnPrefix="TCCMNTS"
            javaType="hashMap"
            ofType="list"
            property="testCaseComments" >
            <id
                column="COMMENT_ID"
                property="id" />
            <result
                column="COMMENT_TEXT"
                property="comment" />
            <result
                column="LOGGING_DATE"
                property="commentedOn" />
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

A test case object has a priority object, created by object, status object, a collection of steps and a collection of comments.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SqlSessionFactory factory = getSqlSessionFactory();
        SqlSession session = factory.openSession();
        List<Map> list = session.selectList("testCaseSelect");
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    }
```

When I run the above, I get a list of 34 hashmaps one for each row returned. Each hashmap contains column_name and its value as key value pairs.

What I wanted is to have a hash map with the following structure:

```
root(hashMap)=>{
           tcid(String),
           title(String),
           description(String),
           createdOn(String),
           testCaseStatus(hashMap)=>{
                                        status(String)
                                    },
           testCasePriority(hashMap)=>{
                                         priority(String)
                                      },
           testCaseCreator(hashMap)=>{
                                         firstName(String),
                                         lastName(String)
                                     },
           testCaseSteps(list of hashMap):[{
                                                stepno(String),
                                                step(String),
                                                result(String),
                                          }],

           testCaseComments(list of hashMap):[{
                                                comment(String),
                                                commentedOn(String)
                                           }],
        }
```

Is it possible to achieve in mybatis?

Comment: I have got he nested hashmap as result. I had made a couple of mistakes in the above example.
1. autoMapping should be false
2. I misunderstood columnPrefix with table suffix, so I removed all the columPrefixes
3. javaType="hashMap" ofType="list" should be the other way   javaType="list" and ofType="hashMap"

Comment: I have got he nested hashmap as result. I had made a couple of mistakes in the above example:
1. autoMapping should be false.
2. I misunderstood columnPrefix with table suffix, so I removed all the columPrefixes.
3. javaType="hashMap" ofType="list" should be the other way   javaType="list" and ofType="hashMap".
4. I added ID fields in the select clause and distinct id property names in the resultmap.